# WYSIWYG editor not displaying buttons and plugins

Tags: 6, users, wysiwyg, input-formats

I'm new to drupal and have not found an answer on SO yet.  I've updated to drupal 6.28, not ready to update to D7 yet, and the WYSIWYG and TinyMCE are not displaying.  Also I can't click/unclick checkboxes for buttons and plugins because I don't see checkboxes!  I also can't

Using `TinyMCE 5.3.8`. Other User Interface modules my site has are `Superfish, jQuery plugins, IMCE Wysiwyg API bridge`

Screenshots below.  Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/McA7x.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzvwa.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at your browser javascript console (native, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), etc.), when the page with TinyMCE is loaded and post any error here (if there is no error, please reload the page). It will make possible to determine the cause of issue.

Comment: This is what I get even after updating superfish module: `Failed to load localized messages: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
sfsmallscreen.js:4`   `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
superfish.js:29`   `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'list.sfsmallscreen(options.plugins.smallscreen)')`

Comment: There is a [thread discussing your problem on drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1981658). Please come back and let us know, if it was useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help milos!  After reverting to previous version and library, superfish has no more js errors